# Videos do not autoplay with audio after user gesture

Tags: javascript, video, mobile-safari, swiper.js, autoplay

I have a simple webpage with multiple `<video>` elements within different slides in a carousel. When a video is in the active slide in the carousel I am `.play()`ing the video and `.pause()`ing all others. I want the videos to autoplay off of mute and am fully aware of each browser's autoplay policies, however even after a user has interacted with the webpage (by pausing/playing/unmuting the first video that plays) any subsequent videos will not play off of mute because of the error:

```
The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

What is the proper way to enable videos to play off of mute after the user has interacted with the page?

I have created a [codesandbox to reproduce the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-video-example-lf9ovm?file=/index.html).

```
      var vid1 = document.getElementById("video1");
      var vid2 = document.getElementById("video2");
      var vid3 = document.getElementById("video3");

      carousel.on("slideChange", function () {
        vid1.currentTime = 0;
        vid2.currentTime = 0;
        vid3.currentTime = 0;
        vid1.pause();
        vid2.pause();
        vid3.pause();

        if (carousel.activeIndex === 0) {
          var currentVideo = vid1;
          var prevVideo = vid3;
        } else if (carousel.activeIndex === 1) {
          var currentVideo = vid2;
          var prevVideo = vid1;
        } else {
          var currentVideo = vid3;
          var prevVideo = vid2;
        }

        currentVideo.volume = 1;
        currentVideo
          .play()
          .catch((e) => {
            console.error(`Error playing: ${e.message}`);
            currentVideo.muted = true;
            return currentVideo
              .play()
              .catch((err) => console.error("Error caught again", err.message));
          })
      });
```

Some additional observations:

- This is only occurring on iOS. Android and desktop browsers work as expected.
- After I play and unumte each video, when the video is revisited, it will then properly play off of mute

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that we were listening for the `touchend` event, after a `touchmove`, which is the gesture registered when swiping. But this is not registered as a user gesture allowing autoplay on iOS.

User gestures that *should* allow autoplay are defined in the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#user-activation-processing-model). Through my testing, I have identified that the only user gestures that allow autoplaying include `click`, `pointerup`, and `mouseup`. `touchend` also works when fired after a `click`, but not after a `touchmove`.

It's also important to understand how to handle user gestures properly as [defined by the Safari team](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/):

> A note about the user gesture requirement: when we say that an action must have happened “as a result of a user gesture”, we mean that the JavaScript which resulted in the call to video.play(), for example, must have directly resulted from a handler for a touchend, click, doubleclick, or keydown event. So, button.addEventListener('click', () => { video.play(); }) would satisfy the user gesture requirement. video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => { video.play(); }) would not.

Comment: thanks for sharing this. Can I just take a moment to mention how terrible it is that that blog post mentions touchend works but doesn't clarify that incredibly important detail? Getting video with sound to play in a 3d app is such a pain with ios safari, jesus...

Comment: I have the same problem. Carousel, if user swipes to next slide while video was playing, I want to start playing the next video. Seems a reasonable policy. Did you end up figuring out a good solution?